# Java: Check whether the string matches the pattern [x.y] where both x and y are between [0-9]

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi guys basically I need to check whether the  version-no is in format x.y where both x and y should be in between[0-9]
Ex:1.1, 1.2, 2.3, 4.5 etc

I am a novice to java....I was thinking of splitting the string using "." and then check whether both are integers....but i think it can be done using regex..which i am not able to do....can anyone help me in this regard...

Comment: try this regex: `\\b\\d+\\.\\d+\\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with regex:

```java
str.matches("\\d\\.\\d")
```

`\d` is a digit, and `\.` is the literal `.` character.